# UIView camera is not saving border to photo

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, border

My code below is a UIView that functions as a camera. When a button (didtakePhoto) is pressed, a border frame is inserted around the UIView. However, the border is not being saved to the photo. The button automatically saves the photo to the photo gallery without the border inserted into the photo. All I want is `sa.layer.addBorder` to be added to the saved photo.

MY CODE

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate  {


var captureSesssion : AVCaptureSession!
var cameraOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput!
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

@IBOutlet var sa: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    captureSesssion = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
        if (captureSesssion.canAddInput(input)) {
            captureSesssion.addInput(input)
            if (captureSesssion.canAddOutput(cameraOutput)) {
                captureSesssion.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSesssion)

                //previewLayer.frame = sa.bounds

                previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 700, height: 700)

                sa.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                captureSesssion.startRunning()
            }}}}

@IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sa.layer.addBorder(edge: [.top], color: UIColor.red, thickness: 12.0)
    sa.layer.addBorder(edge: [.bottom], color: UIColor.red, thickness: 180.0)
    sa.layer.addBorder(edge: [.left], color: UIColor.red, thickness: 100.0)
    sa.layer.addBorder(edge: [.right], color: UIColor.red, thickness: 50.0)



          let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [
        kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
        kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
        kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
    ]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
    cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

    }



    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,  didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,  previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings:  AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings:   AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

                 if let error = error {
            print("error occure : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
            let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
            print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
            let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.imagex(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

                      } else {
            print("some error here")
        }}
    func imagex(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {

    }}
```

Comment: You're not adding the border to the image, you're adding the border to what's essentially it's frame.

Comment: would I put the sa.layer in imagex function @Pierce

Comment: @Pierce that makes sense but where is the image is it in function imagex

Comment: The image in the function `imagex` is just `image` as a `UIImage` but if you look at your code that method gets called after the image is already saved. If you want to manipulate the image before it's saved to the photo album, you're going to have to do it before you call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`

Comment: @Pierce if I wanted to add the border where would I put it in function imagex or capture?  Or move function imagex above the capture function?